How to speed up Ethereum etl blockhain export time?
I am using python module ethereum-etl to parse all specific token transfers from start to end block. As a node I'm running a local snap node with all the receipts being saved parameter (--txlookuplimit 0).
To test this instruments work I've decided to parse USDT token (0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7) transfers from 20_500_000 block to 20_505_000 block. 
The issue I'am having that it works really slow. I am talking taking about 15±0.5 seconds to parse all the transfers. The official docs state that:

You can tune --batch-size, --max-workers for performance.

But tunning --max-workers parameters actually gives me a slight decrease in speed; --batch-size set to 4096 increases speed to 12.4±0.3 seconds, but it's further tweaking worsens the result. 
For my original task I woult need to parse millisons of blocks, so the current speed is unacceptable.
The command I'm running:
ethereumetl export_token_transfers --start-block 20500000 --end-block 20505000 --provider-uri http://127.0.0.1:8545 --output token_transfers.csv  --tokens 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7

I've read this Medium article: How to Export the Entire Ethereum Blockchain to CSV in 2 hours for $10, but I can replicate, since I can't get access to AWS services.
Am I facing a hardware bottleneck or is there something I can do to make it faster?
Would much appreciate any suggestions!

You can try my patch to get all receipts in single RPC call , but you will have to patch Geth and run your own node:
https://github.com/PredictionExplorer/augur-explorer/tree/v2/etl/cmd/layer1/geth-patch
I have it updated up to 1.14.8 version. You would have to subscribe to new blocks, and as soon as a new block comes in, you call this method (getBlockReceipts()) and fetch all the receipts, then you filter them by topic0 and extract what you need. This is the fastest you can get, faster is impossible unless you modify geth and dump the receipts from Geth itself into shared memory (where another process would pick up the data) by modifying Process() function in core/state_processor.go file (in official geth sources). You will also need to keep track of parentHash of every block so you don't get false or duplicated events in case of chain split event and blocks getting reorganized.
